# MapStruct with Gradle and eclipse is not working

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, gradle, mapstruct

Created gradle application using SpringBoot with MapStruct.

Build.gradle file has following entry.

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-jdk8:${mapstructVersion}"
    testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.10', 'org.easytesting:fest-assert:1.4'
    compile "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${mapstructVersion}"
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'net.ltgt.apt-eclipse' version '0.18'
}
```

Mapper class

```
@Mapper(componentModel="spring")
public interface SourceTargetMapper {

    SourceTargetMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(SourceTargetMapper.class);

    @Mapping(source = "qax", target = "baz")
    @Mapping(source = "baz", target = "qax")
    Target sourceToTarget(Source source);

    @InheritInverseConfiguration
    Source targetToSource(Target target);
}
```

Impl file is created under build folder but while running the code getting the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError  at org.mapstruct.example.app.main(app.java:7) Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot
>   find implementation for org.mapstruct.example.SourceTargetMapper  at
>   org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers.getMapper(Mappers.java:68)  at
>   org.mapstruct.example.SourceTargetMapper.(SourceTargetMapper.java:29)
>     ... 1 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find
>   implementation for org.mapstruct.example.SourceTargetMapper   at
>   org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers.getMapper(Mappers.java:85)  at
>   org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers.getMapper(Mappers.java:65)

If I move Impl file from Build folder bin folder it works fine. It means MapStruct create the implementation file under build folder and trying to access it from bin folder.

How to change the location of build files to bin folder?

Working fine with Maven project with M2e plugin but not with gradle.

Build.gradle file after the change suggested.

```
    plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'net.ltgt.apt-eclipse' version '0.18'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) { gradleVersion = '3.4' }

ext {
    mapstructVersion = "1.2.0.Final"
    javaLanguageLevel = '1.8'
    generatedMapperSourcesDir = "${buildDir}/generated-src/mapstruct/main"
}

sourceCompatibility = rootProject.javaLanguageLevel

sourceSets.main {
    ext.originalJavaSrcDirs = java.srcDirs
    java.srcDir "${generatedMapperSourcesDir}"
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-jdk8:${mapstructVersion}"
    testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.10', 'org.easytesting:fest-assert:1.4'
    annotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${mapstructVersion}"
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs = ['-Amapstruct.suppressGeneratorTimestamp=true']
}
```

test { useTestNG() }

But still not working. Please check what is missing.

Comment: I don't see any spring-boot dependency in you build file. can you tell how you build and run the application ? can you poste your main class too.

Comment: an `interface` probably cannot keep an instance; opposite to `abstract class`.

Comment: How was this solved?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the generated sources are not included automatically in the classpath of the application.

Gave a shot to [the sample on github](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/master/mapstruct-on-gradle) and it works fine.

Use the same [gradle config as the sample](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/blob/master/mapstruct-on-gradle/build.gradle) for your application :

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Actually, I am new to java. Can you please suggest what will be the value for 'buildDir' in ${buildDir}/generated-src/mapstruct/main. And how can I specify path to bin folder for generated files?

Comment: ${buildDir} is known by gradle you don't have to specify it.

Comment: I have added the updated gradle.build in the description. Please have a look. It is still not working and getting the same error.

Comment: Looks like the documentation may be for older version of mapStruct. tried the example on github and works fine for me : https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/blob/master/mapstruct-on-gradle/build.gradle